# Average of numbers (Bc command not found error)

Tags: bash

I want to find out the average of the given numbers but following code showing me:

**main.bash: line 8: bc: command not found**

please guys help me out where I was wrong ?

code snnipet:

```
read count
sum=0
for((i=0;i<count;i++))
do
    read var
    sum=`expr $sum + $var`
done
res=`echo "$sum / $count" | bc -l` 
printf "%.3f" $res
```

Comment: Do you have `bc` installed?

Comment: I am using onlinegdb compiler and tutorial points complier it gives me very strange error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `type -a bc`, and if it returns:

```
-bash: type: bc: not found
```

You will then have to install `bc` package in your system.

Comment: Why it's not working on online compiler like onlinegdb, tutorials point, even on hacker rank as well..?

Comment: Probably because the shells running behind the web-based input interfaces do not have the `bc` package installed. The error message you posted is pretty obvious.